# How can I remove text underline from email signature?

Tags: html, css, html-email

```
a.special:visited {color: #FFFFFE; text-decoration-color: #DA4B26 !important; }
```

I'm struggling here. I'm working on an email signature but when it gets input into Gmail, underlines get added. The above text is in the head. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

```
<a class="special" href="https://www.quickreview.co/modplumb/" style="text-decoration:none; border:none; color:#FFFFFE; padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;" class="reviewmgr-button" data-content="Review Us" data-replace="true">
```

Comment: Check this. Gmail is quite tough and ignores some css styles.  https://medium.com/@andreaolivato/remove-underline-from-gmail-signature-links-24e2380c3651

Comment: I'd start by using dev tools to find out where the underline actually comes from.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this tell me whats the output looks like?

```
<a href="https://www.quickreview.co/modplumb/" style="text-decoration:none; border:none; color:#FFFFFE; padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;" data-content="Review Us" data-replace="true">''''
```